# Вложенные структуры

Tags: c++

Позвольте задать еще такой вопрос по структурам:

Пытаюсь создать структуру в котором было бы три подструктуры, но 3-я структура опредлена с отдельно .h файле.

Подобная попытка приводит к ошибке:

> Ошибка    C2079   "my_struct_3::my_struct_2_" использует не имеющую
> определения структуру struct "my_struct_2"

//Struct_3.h

```
#include "Struct_result.h" 

struct my_struct_2;


struct my_struct_3
{
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
};
```

//Struct_result.h

```
#include "Struct_3.h" 

struct my_result;
struct my_struct_3;


struct my_struct_1
{
    int my_int;
};


struct my_struct_2
{
    char my_char;
};



struct my_result
{
    my_struct_1 my_struct_1_;
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
    my_struct_3 my_struct_3_;
};
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "Struct_result.h" 
#include "Struct_3.h" 


int main()
{

}
```

Не понимаю, как правильно в итоге можно вложить все структуры в одну из разных .h файлов ?

Comment: Это так не работает. Предварительное объявление дает возможность работать только с указателями и ссылками — ведь неизвестен ни размер структуры, ни ее "внутренности"...

Comment: @Harry, то есть из другого файла вложить структуру в структуру не получится, не определяя полностью структуру в том файле, где мне ее нужно вложить ?

Comment: @Harry, а вот интересно, если использовать указатели, то как компилятор вычислит смещение поля, если "неизвестен ни размер структуры, ни её внутренности?

Comment: @maestro Смещение поля где? В другой структуре, в которой используется только *указатель*? Так размер самого указателя от типа того, на что он указывает, не зависит. А если вы о смещении полей в предварительно объявленной структуре — то, понятно, никак. Уточните свой вопрос, pls.

Comment: Или я что-то не понимаю, или Вы как-то очень странно распределили структуры по файлам, что привело к циклическим зависимостям по включениям файлов... Вы оба хидера включаете друг в друга, да еще и в срр-шник....

Comment: @Юрий Козлов, разделил по отдельным файлам для удобства, но видимо так не получится.

Comment: Разделить можно. Просто Вы разделили, как по мне, не правильно. Здесь имело бы смысл выносить в отдельный файл ```my_struct_2```, а не ```my_struct_3```, и убирать циклические включения. К слову, здесь Вам предварительные объявления не очень и нужны, поскольку нет циклических зависимостей самих структур. И, к слову, почитайте про организацию заголовочных файлов и защиту от повторного включения. Для начала хоть [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) и [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), дальше, думаю, поймёте, что искать

Comment: @Harry, я говорю о полях вложенной структуры. Нужно упомянуть, что для того, чтобы обратиться к какому-либо полю вложенной структуры, объявленной по указателю, нужно её полное определение, а не предварительное.

Comment: @maestro По-моему, мое *Предварительное объявление дает возможность работать только с указателями и ссылками — ведь неизвестен ни размер структуры, ни ее "внутренности"* именно это и утверждает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите: у вса структура 1 не зависит ни от чего - выносим ее в отдельный h. Структура 2 - тоже, ее тоже даем в отдельном h (или вместе со структурой 1).

Структура 3 зависит от структуры 2 - ее помещаем в свой файл с включением в него h2.

Результирующая зависит от всего - значит, она последняя в своем файле. Итого:

**struct1.h**

```
#pragma once

struct my_struct_1
{
    int my_int;
};
```

**struct2.h**

```
#pragma once

struct my_struct_2
{
    char my_char;
};
```

**struct3.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "struct2.h"

struct my_struct_3
{
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
};
```

**struct_res.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "struct1.h"
#include "struct2.h"
#include "struct3.h"

struct my_result
{
    my_struct_1 my_struct_1_;
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
    my_struct_3 my_struct_3_;
};
```

**struct.cpp**

```
#include "struct_res.h"

int main() {}
```

Но можно и прощзе: собрать всё в один

**struct_res.h**

```
#pragma once

struct my_struct_1
{
    int my_int;
};

struct my_struct_2
{
    char my_char;
};

struct my_struct_3
{
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
};

struct my_result
{
    my_struct_1 my_struct_1_;
    my_struct_2 my_struct_2_;
    my_struct_3 my_struct_3_;
};
```

Главное - отсортировать объявления топологически.